# How to make BubbleMenu Button an Action?

Tags: ios, swift

I have code to do BubbleMenu Buttons, originally from [here](https://github.com/feiin/DWBubbleMenuButton.Swift).

I want to make the BubbleMenu an Action, but I don't know how to.

For example "A" = LogOut, and "B" = LogIn or whatever.

[image: demo]

Here is the code

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  DWBubbleMenuButton.Swift
//
//  Created by feiin on 14/10/25.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 year swiftmi. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var upMenuView:DWBubbleMenuButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func hiddenAll(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("ok")

        upMenuView.dismissButtons()

    }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


                // Create up menu button
        let homeLabel2 =  self.createHomeButtonView()

         upMenuView = DWBubbleMenuButton(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - homeLabel2.frame.size.width - 20.0,self.view.frame.size.height - homeLabel2.frame.size.height - 20.0,
            homeLabel2.frame.size.width,homeLabel2.frame.size.height),expansionDirection: .DirectionUp)
        upMenuView.homeButtonView = homeLabel2

        upMenuView.addButtons(self.createDemoButtonArray())

        self.view.addSubview(upMenuView)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func createHomeButtonView() -> UILabel {

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0))

        label.text = "Tap";
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.size.height / 2.0;
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.0,green:0.0,blue:0.0,alpha:0.5)
        label.clipsToBounds = true;

        return label;
    }

    func createDemoButtonArray() -> [UIButton] {
        var buttons:[UIButton]=[]
        var i = 0
        for str in ["A","B","C","D","E","F"] {
            let button:UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            button.setTitle(str, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0);
            button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.height / 2.0;
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
            button.clipsToBounds = true;
            i += 1


            buttons.append(button)

        }
        return buttons

    }    
}
```

Comment: It's always preferred to be clear about _where_ code came from. It's both a professional courtesy and an aid to understanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean like this?

```
    func createDemoButtonArray() -> [UIButton] {
    var buttons:[UIButton]=[]
    var i = 0
    for str in ["A","B","C","D","E","F"] {
        let button:UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.setTitle(str, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0);
        button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.height / 2.0;
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
        button.clipsToBounds = true;
        i += 1
        buttons.append(button)
        if button.currentTitle == "A" {
            button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("login"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        }
        if button.currentTitle == "B" {
            button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("logout"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        }
    }
    return buttons
}
```

Comment: it's work , but if i make button to do some thing how can i add my button into createDemoButtonArray()

Comment: it's all in the `createDemoButtonArray ` function, you put your button title in the array, and your button will be created with the title and be returned.

Comment: i got error here [ action: Selector("login")] when i click "A"

Comment: maybe my syntax is not right, i haven't written swift for a long time, try this `#selector(ViewController.login)`, and you should implement your `login`, `logout` functions before you call them.

Comment: Thx, bro i do it , [#selector(ViewController.hiddenAll(_:))]